# Testing localhost on browserstack - Safari 8 (on Yosemite) cant open my site

Tags: macos, visual-studio, iis, safari, browserstack

I have problems with testing my site hosted on IIS Express via Browserstack. When I try to open it using Safari 8 (on latest osx) I get message: "Safari cant connect to the server". 
I have tried on other OS or other browsers and it works, but under latest safari it wont... 
Does anyone know what the problem is? 
Im using BS extensions for Firefox or for Chrome.
My serves is running, I have access to it via local browser.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Mukesh here from BrowserStack.

For now, Safari 8 on Yosemite allows Local testing via a limited number of ports. The ports that are most easy to remember are 80,3000, 4000, 5000, 8000 and 8080.

Please note: Public URLs can be tested seamlessly across all ports.

Comment: What about on iOS? I keep getting 'Invalid header received from client'

Comment: @MukeshTiwari It would be great if this was clearly documented *anywhere* on the Browserstack site. Members of the support team apparently don't even know this limitation.

Comment: Indeed, it appears port number is key. 4000 works for me in Chrome on Windows 10 using IIS Express.

Comment: @MukeshTiwari using ports you provided is a progress but Safari still can't load local page. Now instead of "can't connect to server" message safari load indicator is just stuck at ~20%

Comment: @Mukesh thank you. Let's see if BrowserStack follows up on my request: https://twitter.com/browserstack/status/897030152185667584

Comment: Still have this problem, latest safari, https:// doesnt seem to work, but http:// does

Answer (score 3):

In case you need more ports than the ones mentioned by Mukesh, it seems like the range between 9000 and 9999 is open in Safari (and BrowserStack) for local testing.